# Including style in RestKit RKObjectMapping json

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

When I map the nested json below with `RestKit RKObjectMapping` in swift, it'll return error. because `extra` has `style`. if `extra` excepts `style`, it'll be ok. style is for reserved word?
How can I fix it? Thanks.

```
{
    "sucess": true,
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": ""
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
            "extra": {
                "style": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

mapping code.

```
class func responseMapping() -> RKObjectMapping {
    let objectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: self)
    objectMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
        "id": "id",
        "name": "name",
        "extra": "extra"
    ])

    return objectMapping
}
```

I'm using like this.

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObject(self,
    path: path,
    parameters: params,
    success: { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, result: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in
            completionHandler(Result(result.array() as! [Content]))
    }) { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            completionHandler(Result(error))
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Show your mapping code.

Comment: @Wain thanks for your reply. I added my mapping code. I can't get error by above code. How can I get error message?